# How can I solve equations in Python?

Tags: python, calculator, equation

Let's say I have an equation:

`2x + 6 = 12`

With algebra we can see that `x = 3`. How can I make a program in Python that can solve for `x`? I'm new to programming, and I looked at `eval()` and `exec()` but I can't figure out how to make them do what I want. I do not want to use external libraries (e.g. SAGE), I want to do this in just plain Python.

Comment: If you want to solve any equation you will have to build your own library. Also 4.5 seconds isn't fast enough for this example :D

Comment: Are the problems always going to look like `solve y = mx + c for x`?

Comment: @MikePennington: if he only wants to allow a very restricted set of equations, it's perfectly doable. In the abstract case, of course, you  would have to build your own symbolic math engine a-la `maxima` or `Mathematica`, but I don't think that's the intent.

Answer (score 43):

How about [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html)? Their [solver](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/solvers/solvers.html) looks like what you need. Have a look at their source code if you want to build the library yourself…

Answer (score 30):

There are two ways to approach this problem: numerically and symbolically.

To solve it numerically, you have to first encode it as a "runnable" function - stick a value in, get a value out. For example,

```
def my_function(x):
    return 2*x + 6
```

It is quite possible to parse a string to automatically create such a function; say you parse `2x + 6` into a list, `[6, 2]` (where the list index corresponds to the power of x - so 6*x^0 + 2*x^1). Then:

```
def makePoly(arr):
    def fn(x):
        return sum(c*x**p for p,c in enumerate(arr))
    return fn

my_func = makePoly([6, 2])
my_func(3)    # returns 12
```

You then need another function which repeatedly plugs an x-value into your function, looks at the difference between the result and what it wants to find, and tweaks its x-value to (hopefully) minimize the difference.

```
def dx(fn, x, delta=0.001):
    return (fn(x+delta) - fn(x))/delta

def solve(fn, value, x=0.5, maxtries=1000, maxerr=0.00001):
    for tries in xrange(maxtries):
        err = fn(x) - value
        if abs(err) < maxerr:
            return x
        slope = dx(fn, x)
        x -= err/slope
    raise ValueError('no solution found')
```

There are lots of potential problems here - finding a good starting x-value, assuming that the function actually has a solution (ie there are no real-valued answers to x^2 + 2 = 0), hitting the limits of computational accuracy, etc. But in this case, the error minimization function is suitable and we get a good result:

```
solve(my_func, 16)    # returns (x =) 5.000000000000496
```

Note that this solution is not *absolutely, exactly* correct. If you need it to be perfect, or if you want to try solving families of equations analytically, you have to turn to a more complicated beast: a symbolic solver.

A symbolic solver, like Mathematica or Maple, is an expert system with a lot of built-in rules ("knowledge") about algebra, calculus, etc; it "knows" that the derivative of sin is cos, that the derivative of kx^p is kpx^(p-1), and so on. When you give it an equation, it tries to find a path, a set of rule-applications, from where it is (the equation) to where you want to be (the simplest possible form of the equation, which is hopefully the solution).

Your example equation is quite simple; a symbolic solution might look like:

```
=> LHS([6, 2]) RHS([16])

# rule: pull all coefficients into LHS
LHS, RHS = [lh-rh for lh,rh in izip_longest(LHS, RHS, 0)], [0]

=> LHS([-10,2]) RHS([0])

# rule: solve first-degree poly
if RHS==[0] and len(LHS)==2:
    LHS, RHS = [0,1], [-LHS[0]/LHS[1]]

=> LHS([0,1]) RHS([5])
```

and there is your solution: x = 5.

I hope this gives the flavor of the idea; the details of implementation (finding a good, complete set of rules and deciding when each rule should be applied) can easily consume many man-years of effort.

Answer (score 12):

Python may be good, but it isn't God...

There are a few different ways to solve equations. SymPy has already been mentioned, if you're looking for analytic solutions.

If you're happy to just have a numerical solution, Numpy has a few routines that can help. If you're just interested in solutions to polynomials, numpy.roots will work. Specifically for the case you mentioned:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.roots([2,-6])
array([3.0])
```

For more complicated expressions, have a look at scipy.fsolve.

Either way, you can't escape using a library.

Comment: Unless you know your numerical methods hardcore, you can't, which anyways is probable to render a worse result than some robust library

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to solve the **extremely limited** set of equations `mx + c = y` for positive integer `m, c, y`, then this will do:

```
import re
def solve_linear_equation ( equ ):
    """
    Given an input string of the format "3x+2=6", solves for x.
    The format must be as shown - no whitespace, no decimal numbers,
    no negative numbers.
    """
    match = re.match(r"(\d+)x\+(\d+)=(\d+)", equ)
    m, c, y = match.groups()
    m, c, y = float(m), float(c), float(y) # Convert from strings to numbers
    x = (y-c)/m
    print ("x = %f" % x)
```

Some tests:

```
>>> solve_linear_equation("2x+4=12")
x = 4.000000
>>> solve_linear_equation("123x+456=789")
x = 2.707317
>>>
```

If you want to recognise and solve **arbitrary** equations, like `sin(x) + e^(i*pi*x) = 1`, then you will need to implement some kind of symbolic maths engine, similar to `maxima`, `Mathematica`, MATLAB's `solve()` or Symbolic Toolbox, etc. As a novice, this is beyond your ken.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different tool. Something like [Wolfram Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com/), [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/), [R](http://www.r-project.org/), [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.de/products/matlab/) or any other algebra software package.

As a beginner you should probably not attempt to solve such a non-trivial problem.