# Is there any module that can handle unidentified variables?

Tags: python, variables, math, algebra

Ok, so I am trying to make a program that can find the **time** of a car when two cars are speeding away from each other at a certain speed, each with a different rate that is only given the **rate** using time=distance/rate. But I would need a expression with a unsolved, variable, to do problems like the following:

*Car1 is going 20mph. Car2 is going 10mph faster than Car1. Car2 left one hour later than Car1. How long would it take Car2 to catch up with Car1?*

And my work without a program:

```
t = Travel time total (in hours)

10*t = 20(t-1) # Note the 1 is for the 1 hour

# rearrange
10*t = 20*t - 20

# subtract 10*t from both sizes
0 = 10*t - 20

# add 20 to both sides
20 = 10*t

#divide both sizes by 10
2 = t
```

Is there a module that supports operations with undefined variables using the distributive property (i.e. which can solve equations like this one)?

If not, than could I have a small example of how I would use unidentified variables without a module? I just went over this in school.

Comment: duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499941/how-can-i-solve-equations-in-python

Comment: As a warning, please stop bouncing between rolling back edits to bump your question to the front page. This is an abuse of the edit system.

Comment: I am sorry. I actually didn't know it did that. I was just happy cuz my question was answered. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module you are looking for is called [SymPy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/).

```
import sympy
t = sympy.Symbol('t') # set t as a variable/symbol
sympy.solve(sympy.Eq(10*t, 20*(t-1)), t) # which reads: solve the equation 10*t == 20*(t-1) for t.
# returns [2] (list of solutions to the equation)
```

*(see some more [quick examples](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Quick-examples) of using SymPy).*

Comment: Didn't know about this module, nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
def get_time(v1, v2, dt):
    t = (v2*dt)/(v2 - v1)
    return t
```

Then you can call the function with the velocities of car1, car2 and the offset, and it will return the time you want.