# How to solve Equation without any Modules in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to solve this equation without any Modules(NumPy, Sympy... etc.)

Px + Qy = W

(ex. 5x + 6y = 55)

Thanks.

Comment: What answer are you looking for? You have 1 equation but 2 variables. Do you need `x(y) = ...` or `y(x) = ...`?

Comment: @Sqoshu Sorry. I mean the code that outputs the x and y values that satisfy the equation.

Comment: Well in this case you don't have anything other to do than to just brute-force your way with for loops, iterating thru values over certain range and accepting some error, as this sort of task will have infinite answers over all numbers.

Comment: I see. Thank you for helping me! Have a good day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very crude way to do this, but you can use brute-force technique, as I said in comment under your question. It can probably be optimized a lot, gives only `int` outputs, but overall shows the method:

```
import numpy as np

# Provide the equation:
print("Provide a, b and c to evaluate in equation of form {ax + by - c = 0}")
a = float(input("a: "))
b = float(input("b: "))
c = float(input("c: "))

x_range = int(input("x-searching range (-a, a): "))
y_range = int(input("y-searching range (-b, b): "))
error = float(input("maximum accepted error from the exact solution: "))

x_range = np.arange(-x_range, x_range, 1)
y_range = np.arange(-y_range, y_range, 1)

for x in x_range:
    for y in y_range:
        if -error <= a * x + b * y - c <= error:
            print("Got an absolute error of {} or less with numbers x = {} and y = {}.".format(error, x, y))
```

Example output for `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 3`, `x_range = 10`, `y_range = 10`, `error = 0.001`:

```
Got an error of 0.001 or less with numbers x = -9 and y = 6.
Got an error of 0.001 or less with numbers x = -7 and y = 5.
Got an error of 0.001 or less with numbers x = -5 and y = 4.
Got an error of 0.001 or less with numbers x = -3 and y = 3.
Got an error of 0.001 or less with numbers x = -1 and y = 2.
Got an error of 0.001 or less with numbers x = 1 and y = 1.
Got an error of 0.001 or less with numbers x = 3 and y = 0.
Got an error of 0.001 or less with numbers x = 5 and y = -1.
Got an error of 0.001 or less with numbers x = 7 and y = -2.
Got an error of 0.001 or less with numbers x = 9 and y = -3.
```

I am using `numpy`, but not a built-in function to solve the equation itself, just to create an array. This can be done without it, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands of ways to solve an equation with python.

One of those is:

```
def myfunc (x=None, y=None):
    return ((55-6*y)/5.0) if y else ((55-5*x)/6.0)


print(myfunc(x=10)) # OUTPUT: 0.833333333333, y value for x == 10
print(myfunc(y=42)) # OUTPUT: -39.4, x value for y == 42
```

You simply define inside a function the steps required to solve the equation.
In our example, if we have `y` value we subtract `6*y` to `55` then we divide by `5.0` (we add .0 to have a float as result), otherwise (means we have `x`) we subtract `5*x` from `55` and then we divide by `6.0`

with the same principle, you can generalize:

```
def myfunc (x=None, y=None, P=None, Q=None, W=None):
    if not W:
        return P*x + Q*y
    elif not x:
        return (W-Q*y)/float(P)
    elif not y:
        return (W-P*x)/float(Q)
    elif not P:
        return (W-Q*y)/float(x)
    elif not Q:
        return (W-P*x)/float(y)


print(myfunc(x=10, P=5, Q=6, W=55)) # OUTPUT: 0.833333333333, y value for x == 10
print(myfunc(y=42, P=5, Q=6, W=55)) # OUTPUT: -39.4, x value for y == 42
```

check [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499941/how-can-i-solve-equations-in-python) for some other interesting ways to approach this problem

Comment: Thankyou for give me answer! But I mean the code that outputs the x and y values that satisfy the equation.