# How to find unknown variable in matrices, A=B in python?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sympy, equation

I have matrices A which have unknown variables and have a solution matrices B.Now I have to find unknown variables by doing A=B.
How I can do this through python?

```
   [sin⁡(f)cos⁡(e) sin⁡(d)sin⁡(e)cos⁡(f)−sin⁡(f)cos⁡(d)  sin⁡(d)sin⁡(f)+sin⁡(e)cos⁡(d)cos⁡(f)   0]  
A= [sin⁡(f)cos⁡(e) sin⁡(d)sin⁡(e)sin⁡(f)+cos⁡(d)cos⁡(f) −sin⁡(d)cos⁡(f)+sin⁡(e)sin⁡(f)cos⁡(d)   0]
   [−sin⁡(e)      sin⁡(d)cos⁡(e)                     cos⁡(d)cos⁡(e)                      0] 
   [0             0                                0                                1]

   [0.23 -0.45 1.6 0]
B= [0.8   1.7  1.4 0]
   [0.43  0.72 0.6 0]
   [0     0.   0.  1] 

A = B
```

Comment: This is very abstract. Why not solve by hand? You know `sin(e)`, and therefore `e`. Any other element in the second-to-last row therefore gives you `d`, while the first column gives you `f`.

Comment: The Orginal Equation is more complex, this is part of Robotics and Automation Inverse Kinematics.

Comment: That doesn't help any. You could try sympy, but you can't reasonably expect an answer tailored to your needs if you don't present an example of what you actually want (and the research you've done so far).

Comment: I just want to know that there is some function of Sympy which can calculate it and give me the answer of unknown variables

Answer (score 1):

How about [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html)? Their [solver](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/solvers/solvers.html) looks like what you need.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499941/how-can-i-solve-equations-in-python), you'll find other relevant resources.

You can find examples in [SymPy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/units/examples.html) and in the [SymPy Github project](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Quick-examples).

Good luck!

Comment: links for examples added to the answer.